# Is there any dot net framework available to create micro services and domain driven model

Tags: .net

In our project we have planned to implement microservices and domain driven. So we need different type of dot net framework for flexibility. we found some of the frameworks which is mentioned below. Is there any .NET related framework available apart from what I mentioned?

1. MicrodotFramework
2. Asp.netBiolerPlate
3. NancyFX
4. CQRSLite
5. ServiceStack
6. AKKa.Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://steeltoe.io/

> Cloud-native .NET microservices
>   Steeltoe is an open source project that enables .NET developers to implement industry standard best practices when building resilient microservices for the cloud. The Steeltoe client libraries enable .NET Core and .NET Framework apps to easily leverage Netflix Eureka, Hystrix, Spring Cloud Config Server, and Cloud Foundry services.

Comment: steel toe is good. Do you know any other framework  @Wael Abbas

Comment: Check this one also https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/894355/MicroService-Net-Create-Micro-Services-Easily-with